# Can anyone help me in find the number of xml tag occurences using awk or sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have to write a script that will count the number of xml tags(say Code) in a xml file using shell script. XML file can be anyone of the following formats:

```
Format #1: 
<Code>value1</Code> <Code>value2</Code>

 Format #2: 
<Code Attr1=va>value1</Code> <Code Attr1=va
Attr2=va>value1</Code>

Format #3: 
<Code>value1</Code><Code>value2</Code> (All Codes can be in
a single line or multiple lines)

Format #4 
   <Code Attr1=va>value1</Code><Code Attr2=va>value1</Code>

Format #5: 
<Cod 
e>Value1</Code
<Code Attr=1> </C
ode>
```

In short XML file can in any format and can have new lines anywhere. 
Please help me, I need to do this soon..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regular expressions are a bad way to parse XML, using some sort of XML parser is better.**

If you really want to use sed/awk/shell/grep etc, the first thing I can think of is:

```
 cat tst | xargs | grep -o '<\s*C\s*o\s*d\s*e[^>]*>' | wc -l
```

I don't know awk very well, but I'm sure there are awk ninjas out there who can do it more elegantly than this.

It only counts occurences of `<Code>` (& variations) but not the closing tag, so if you have  (for example) 10 `<Code>` in your file but only 9 `</Code>`, it will return 10 and not 9.

Basically:

- `cat tst | xargs` cats 'tst' to the shell all on one line (so I don't have to worry about new lines);
- `grep -o '<\s*C\s*o\s*d\s*e[^>]*>'` prints all matches of `<Code{optional other stuff}>` where you can have newlines/spaces in between all letters of `Code` (the `-o` prints *just* the matches to the regex, one per line);
- `wc -l` counts the lines.

Try each bit successively to see what I mean.

For me `tst` was just a copy-paste of what you have above.

```
[foo@bar ~]$cat tst
Format #1: 
<Code>value1</Code> <Code>value2</Code>

 Format #2: 
<Code Attr1=va>value1</Code> <Code Attr1=va
Attr2=va>value1</Code>

Format #3: 
<Code>value1</Code><Code>value2</Code> (All Codes can be in
a single line or multiple lines)

Format #4 
   <Code Attr1=va>value1</Code><Code Attr2=va>value1</Code>

Format #5: 
<Cod 
e>Value1</Code
<Code Attr=1> </C
ode>

[foo@bar ~]$cat tst | xargs
Format #1: <Code>value1</Code> <Code>value2</Code> Format #2: <Code Attr1=va>value1</Code> <Code Attr1=va Attr2=va>value1</Code> Format #3: <Code>value1</Code><Code>value2</Code> (All Codes can be in a single line or multiple lines) Format #4 <Code Attr1=va>value1</Code><Code Attr2=va>value1</Code> Format #5: <Cod e>Value1</Code <Code Attr=1> </C ode>

[foo@bar ~]$cat tst | xargs | grep -o '<\s*C\s*o\s*d\s*e[^>]*>'
<Code>
<Code>
<Code Attr1=va>
<Code Attr1=va Attr2=va>
<Code>
<Code>
<Code Attr1=va>
<Code Attr2=va>
<Cod e>
<Code Attr=1>

[foo@bar ~]$cat tst | xargs | grep -o '<\s*C\s*o\s*d\s*e[^>]*>' | wc -l
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the XML into into the document tree via DOMParser or XMLDOM as appropriate. Then use jQuery $(xml).find("code") to return an array of  occurrences. The length of the array gives you the count.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick and Dirty way:

Since the xml file have different types of tags, here is a quick and dirty way to get an approximation of xml-tags in your file.

```
awk -v FS="" '
BEGIN{rc=lc=0} 
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/</) {lc++} else if ($i~/>/) {rc++}}
END{print "< = "lc " and > = "rc}' xmlfile
```

#### Sample File:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat xmlfile
Format #1: 
<Code>value1</Code> <Code>value2</Code>

 Format #2: 
<Code Attr1=va>value1</Code> <Code Attr1=va
Attr2=va>value1</Code>

Format #3: 
<Code>value1</Code><Code>value2</Code> (All Codes can be in
a single line or multiple lines)

Format #4 
   <Code Attr1=va>value1</Code><Code Attr2=va>value1</Code>

Format #5: 
<Cod 
e>Value1</Code>
<Code Attr=1> </C
ode>
```

#### Execution:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="" '
    BEGIN{rc=lc=0} 
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/</) {lc++} else if ($i~/>/) {rc++}}
    END{print "< = "lc " and > = "rc}' xmlfile
< = 20 and > = 20
```

We now have an idea that there are `20 * <` and `20 * >`. So you can have an approximation that there are 10 xml-tags in your file, as `<code>` and `</code>` makes 1 tag.

The reason I am saying it as an approximation because there may be `>` or `<` in your file which may not be a part of xml-tag. This can be a start certainly not the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might(?) work for you:

```
sed -n ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/<\s*\/[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]*\s*>/\n&\n/gp' example |
sed -n 's/^<\//</p' | 
sort | 
uniq -c
9 <Code>
```

If you have more exotic element names you will need to amend `[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]*` to whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If *XML gawk* is an option:

```
xmlgawk -lxml 'END { print c }
XMLSTARTELEM == "Code" { c++ }
  ' input.xml
```